# Regex to move text to an associated anchor and wrap it in a span

Tags: php, regex

I have the HTML output currently as this:

```
<a href="#">Coats</a> (12)
```

What I'd like to do, is a regex or operation that moves the number to inside anchor in such a way:

```
<a href="#">Coats<span>12</span></a>
```

The output is ALWAYS in same format I posted. I simply looking to eliminate the ( ) and wrap it in span, and put it without any space inside the HTML structure for anchor.

**(DID NOT try anything because I do not know anything close, about regex)**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $html = preg_replace('|<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a> \((\d+?)\)|i', 
         '<a href="$1">$2<span>$3</span></a>', $html);
```

With the caveat that regular expressions should not generally be used to manipulate HTML.

Comment: Sorry Matt, what if the href is variable? Is there quick way to fix this?

Comment: @AhmedFouad You should also update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the period with non-greedy quantifiers like `.+?` which will not match everything (like newlines), I would use

- non-matching character class `[^blah]`
- and take care of whitespace between elements of a tag considering it
  is valid in HTML (as shown in sample input)

*Regex:*

```
(<a\s*href[^>]+>[^<]+)(<\/a>)\s*\(([^)]+)\)
```

*Replace with:*

```
$1<span>$3</span>$2
```

*Test here:*

http://regexr.com?324j8

*PHP code:*

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/(<a\s*href[^>]+>[^<]+)(<\/a>)\s*\(([^)]+)\)/','$1<span>$3</span>$2','<a href="#">Coats</a> (12)');
?>
```

*Sample Input:*

```
<a href="#">Coats</a> (12)
<a  href="#">Coats</a> (35)
<a href ="#">Coats</a>   (234546)
<a    href= "#">Coats</a>(1)
<a href="#" >Coats</a> (BlahBlah)
```

*Sample Output:*

```
<a href="#">Coats<span>12</span></a>
<a href="#">Coats<span>35</span></a>
<a href ="#">Coats<span>234546</span></a>
<a href= "#">Coats<span>1</span></a>
<a href="#" >Coats<span>BlahBlah</span></a>
```